# how to use squeeze theorem to show that $|f_n(x)|\le 1$ implies $|f(x)|\le 1$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand that in the case we have $a_n\le b_n\le c_n$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}c_n$, we know that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}c_n$. But I had a hard time to use this theorem to show that $|f_n(x)|\le 1$ implies $|f(x)|\le 1$, given $\lim_{ n\to \infty} f_n = f$.

Comment: You did not say what $f$ is, and how it is related to the $f_n$.

Comment: *“but Squeeze theorem requires all three to be sequences”* – You can define a sequence $(a_n)$ by $a_n = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @MartinR, Sorry I added one more assumption. $\lim_{ n\to \infty} f_n = f$.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use this theorem. We don't even know that $|f(x)|\geq |f_n(x)|$ for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$ or $|f(x)|\leq |f_n(x)|$.

However, given $x\in I$ where $I$ is the domain of convergence, we know that:

$\lim f_n(x)=f(x)$. Since $-1\leq f_n(x)\leq 1$, it must be that $-1\leq\lim f_n(x)=f(x)\leq 1$ - otherwise we can find such $\varepsilon >0$ for which $f_n(x)>1+\varepsilon$ or $f_n(x)<-1-\varepsilon$ from a certain point, which is of course a contradiction. So this shows that $|f(x)|\leq  1$

Comment: Thank you. Your argument makes sense to me. But in professor's notes, he mentioned a lot "by Squeeze Theorem" on this type of argument, so I really want to know how to use Squeeze Theorem to complete this kind of proof.

Comment: @maskeran The squeeze theorem speaks of limits. You want to prove that $f$ is bounded. I don't see the connection.